# Nordic nRF51 DK on Mac with CrossWorks

Tags: arm, bluetooth-lowenergy, nrf51

On OSX with Rowley Associates CrossWorks what are the steps needed to compile and run a simple BLE UART sample code for Nordic nRF51 DK to an iPhone.

I found iOS and Android code here and am comfortable with that part: https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/nRFready-Demo-APPS

But I am not sure how to get the toolchain setup and running on the nRF51 board. I've seen some directions for SDK 6.x but can't find anything for SDK 7.x.

Comment: I've had success building the examples and programming the nRF51 DH using ARM GCC and following these instructions:
https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/blogs/22/getting-started-with-nrf51-development-on-mac-os-x/
Do you need to use CrossWorks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I got it to work:

1. Setup "[nRF51 SDK](http://developer.nordicsemi.com/nRF51_SDK/nRF51_SDK_v8.x.x/)"
2. unzip "[nRF51_SDK_8.0.0_5fc2c3a_packs](http://developer.nordicsemi.com/nRF51_SDK/nRF51_SDK_v8.x.x/nRF51_SDK_8.0.0_5fc2c3a_packs.zip)/nRF_SoftDevice_S110/NordicSemiconductor.nRF_SoftDevice_S110.8.0.0.pack"
3. Load "$[nRF51_SDK_8.0.0_5fc2c3a](http://developer.nordicsemi.com/nRF51_SDK/nRF51_SDK_v8.x.x/nRF51_SDK_8.0.0_5fc2c3a.zip)/components/softdevice/s110/hex/s110_softdevice.hex" on nRF51 with [RKNRFGO.app](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rknrfgo/)
4. In CrossWorks File->Import Project and select "$nRF51_SDK_8.0.0_5fc2c3a/examples/ble_peripheral/[ble_app_uart](http://developer.nordicsemi.com/nRF51_SDK/nRF51_SDK_v8.x.x/doc/8.0.0/s110/html/a00072.html)"

5.in "Select Template" select "nRF51_EXE - ..."template list

6. Remove "[retarget.c](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/question/29200/retargeting/)" from project (it is easiest if you build now so you get the error)
7. Select Project Item-> "Project 'nrf51422_xxac_s110'" in project explorer
8. In "Properties Window" scroll down to "Linker Options" and set "Section Placement Macros" to:

   FLASH_START=0x18000

   RAM_START=0x20002000

Also make sure Properties Window->Target Loader Options->**Can Erase All** is set to "**No**"

9. Select Build->nrf51422_xxac_s110...

9.5 Select Target -> Connect -> SEGGER J-LINK

10. Select Debug->Go

Now apps can connect to the [nRF51 DK](https://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/nRF51-DK) board

- [iOS app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/nrf-uart/id614594903?mt=8)
- [Android App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nordicsemi.nrfUARTv2&hl=en) is the Android version.

Get the mobile app source code [here](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/nRFready-Demo-APPS).

See [this](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/question/31440/nrf51_sdk_800-ble_stack_init-hangs/) post for more details.

Comment: Step-by-step debugging worked for me on OS X, Crossworks, nRF51-DK, only after importing what's inside "../nRF51_SDK_8.0.0/examples/ble_peripheral/ble_app_uart/pca10028/arm4" for SDK 8.0.0. If you have a recent mac, I have to recommend virtualbox/win7/keil combo as it's "unfortunately" a lot faster to setup for beginners. Eventually I'll move on to CW to avoid paying Keil a fortune, also I find virtual windows only uglier than it's native state. When you'd think windows can't get any worse, they created windows on vm. Yet it works out of the box.